# Problems with ActiveRecord and LINQ queries

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I have a simple class:

```
public class User : ActiveRecordLinqBase<User>
{
    [PrimaryKey(Column = "user_id", Length = 20)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "password", Length = 16)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and I have created the following repository:

```
public class SqlRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : ActiveRecordLinqBase<T>, new() {
    public void Add(T entity) {
        entity.SaveAndFlush();
    }

    public void Remove(T entity) {
        entity.DeleteAndFlush();
    }

    public void Modify(T entity) {
        entity.UpdateAndFlush(); ;
    }

    ...

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Func<T, bool> predicate) {
        return ActiveRecordLinqBase<T>.Queryable.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Now, when running the following unit test (against a MySQL database):

```
[Test]
public void Test_Sample() {
    var repo = new SqlRepository<T>();
    repo.Add("john.doe", "keyword1");
    repo.Add("other.user", "keyword2");

    var users = repo.FindAll(x => x.Username.Contains("john")).ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(1, users.Count);
}
```

... I get the following SQL query:

> SELECT this_.user_id as user1_0_0_, this_.password as password0_0_, this_.role as role0_0_ FROM users this_

Where is the `WHERE` clause?

If I instead do the following in the same test directly...

```
var users = User.Queryable.Where(x => x.Username.Contains("john"));
```

I get the following SQL:

> SELECT this_.user_id as user1_0_0_, this_.password as password0_0_, this_.role as role0_0_ FROM users this_ WHERE this_.user_id like ?p0;?p0 = '%john%'

**Am I doing something wrong?**

**What is the difference between those two queries?**

---

**Edit:** I also tried with

```
return ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<T>().Where(predicate);
```

without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now this is just because I like code, and sometimes I notice stuff... I'm no expert on Active Record, so this is just a guess...

Maybe you should change the signature of the `FindAll` method from

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Func<T, bool> predicate)
```

into

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
```

which will allow you to hit the right overload of `Where`, which is most likely the overload you're looking for.

It's because a `Func` can't be reflected upon the same way an `Expression of Func` can.

Comment: Spent about 2.5 hours on it :/ Thank you very much ;)